# Popup page in Master detail swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, popup, master-detail

I want to  show popup viewcontroller after masterdetail page but when i call for method for show popup page , add popup page to subview in detail page
i want show popup in full screen in ipad but i dont know how to use it

detail page code :

```
let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AppDescSoryID") as! ApplicationDetailViewController
    if let catIndex = (TableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?)?.row
    {
        popOverVC.ReciveData = self.categoryFilter[catIndex]
    }


    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame//FeatureViewController.screenSize
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```